# Specializing with two template arguments for an argument (C++ template)

Tags: c++, templates

I have no idea how to describe this question properly, but basically what I want to know is something like this can be compiled without a problem:

```
// prototype
template <class T>
void pretty_function(T arg);

// specialization
template <class U, class V>
void pretty_function<U<V>>(T arg);
```

So I want to specialize the type **T** with the type **U< V >**, where the type **U** requires a template argument **V**. I think I can easily test this on my local workstation, but I just leave it here for the future reference.

Comment: Well, for one, `T` should be `U<V>` in the last one. There is no `T` in that specialization. Secondly, should that template argument list look something like `template <template<class> class U, class V>` ? Or is the partial specialization complaint that is the real problem you're facing ?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to declare a specialization of `pretty_function` that would accept only types of the form `U<V>` where `U` can be any class template and `V` can be any type. This would be a *partial* specialization since the template argument `T` is not fully specified. C++ does not support partial specialization of function templates. The usual workaround is to dispatch to a helper class template that can be partially specialized:

```
namespace detail {
    template <class T>
    struct pretty_function_helper {
        static void doit(T arg) { /* implementation */ }
    };

    // partial specialization
    template <template <class> class U, class V>
    struct pretty_function_helper<U<V>> {
        static void doit(U<V> arg) { /* implementation */ }
    };
}

template <class T> void pretty_function(T arg) {
    detail::pretty_function_helper<T>::doit(arg);
}
```

Comment: Hmm it's too bad that C++ doesn't support partial specialization for functions. Thanks :)

Comment: Brian, is there a reason a simple overload wouldn't work here? [Something like this](https://ideone.com/bXjEpV). I rarely need to do this, only reason I'm asking.

Comment: @WhozCraig For my case, it was just for coding convenience. When it comes to handling STL containers, simple overloading requires exactly the same code duplicated for each container (set, vector, list, etc.)

Comment: But I solved my own problem without using this hack cause I don't want my code untidy. I just created separate prototypes for those that need to be partially specialized if it was possible.